# Terraform: AWS attach NAT gateway to one subnet among two

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating two public subnets in two different AZ's using Terraform `count.index` which is looping through two different CIDR's and AZ's in a list. Up to this is correct. Now I have to create a NAT gateway and attach it to only one of the public subnets created above.
When passing `subnet_id = aws_subnet.this[count.index].id` it is attaching NAT gateway to both the public subnets.

How do I attach a NAT gateway to only one of the public subnets among two using terraform?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to share your Terraform code as a [mcve] that reproduces the issue you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see if it is using `count.index` your NAT gateway resource must be using the `count` parameter.

If you want only one NAT Gateway do not use the `count` parameter in the NAT Gateway resource, if you want the first subnet from this resource instead use `subnet_id = aws_subnet.this[0].id`.